# Java jdbc program error getting in program while running it no suitable class found

Tags: java, jdbc

I get problem to run a jdbc program not getting output error is suitable driver not found I added jar file but also[this is my program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMdEM.jpg) getting a problem

Comment: Please add the code here, rather that showing the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

You must correct your connection string:

```
Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnction("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/student1", "Admin", "msdos");
```

More info here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-url-format.html